# Word for "strictly" parve

Tags: kashrut-kosher, words, meat-and-milk, chazaka

What word do people use to identify something as completely parve--that is, kosher to eat with meat or milk--as distinct from "b'chezkat chalavi/basari"/DE/nat bar nat?

Would it be correct to say "l'chatchila parve" for this? Or is there another word?

Comment: כשר פרווה, כשר למאכלי בשר וחלב.         Almost sure

Comment: @kouty,  כשר פרווה can also refer to fish, which most will not eat with meat and some won't eat with milk

Comment: @Noach MiFrankfurt yes you are right

Comment: @kouty Thanks so much! If you post this as an answer, I shall G-d willing accept

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I thought of expressly excluding fish in my question, then figured it wasn't worth it. But you're right.

Comment: @Noach Do you know of any term for this that would exclude fish by that token?

Comment: @SAH Iam not sure 100%

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt raised a tremendously valid point that I didn't think of! This may place an ambiguity within the kashrut market that no one seems to have addressed. "Parve" only defines things as being usable with either meat or dairy foods. But if the item has fish, it's still parve, and, not everyone marks the fish contents in it! Some might designate it, but, not everyone. SAH, perhaps, this is something to relay to a mashgiach. I know one in my neighborhood, and B"N, I'll ask him about this issue.

Comment: While I haven't seen this, I think that one should assume that the "pareve" label does **not** contain fish, unless, of course it actually **is** fish. I think you can easily identify fish :-) Worcestershire (I spelt it wright?) I believe contains anchovies, and you can find an article, I think on Star-K or CRC web site, that discusses if this is considered "fish" or not (may be *batul bishishim*). At any rate, I have seen something like "OU-fish" on a label, so some kashrut agencies are careful. A safe bet is to read the ingredients. I highly doubt that your Shabbat challah has fish in it.

Comment: @DanF, anchovies are the ikkar of Worcestershire sauce (Wikipedia.org/wiki/Worcestershire_sauce)

Comment: Vegan parve? :-)

Comment: @DanF I'm not worried about this distinction because imo the fish thing has nothing to do with kashrus; it's a sakana or something

Comment: @DanF OK maybe the fish and milk has (vaguely) to do with kashrus

Comment: ...The meat/fish stuff is correspondingly more lenient than kashrus I think. I was told I don't need a fish knife, for example. For all these reasons, i consider the whole inyan separate from my question

Comment: The fish notation is considered a kashrut issue if you're talking about labeling a product, which is the basis of your question, right? If you're already asking about the parve status on a product, then you're asking about kashrut labeling. In other words, the "origin" of why fish & meat (or milk) being from *sakana* is irrelevant to why (most) everyone still practices this rule. They do, even though the *sakanah* no longer is there, these days. So, it's considered a "kashrut" issue. You definitely need to know about the fish status, whether it's labeled or you need to read the ingredients.

Comment: "I was told I don't need a fish knife" - Not for kashrut, directly. But, you should be sure that that knife is really cleaned from fish if you will be using it for meat, afterwards. (It's not as easy as you think to clean fish from knives and pots, etc. Ever cook home-made gefilte fish? Then you know!) Otherwise, you really do need a dedicated fish knife for proper filleting.

Comment: @kouty "כשר למאכלי בשר וחלב" - Nope! I think this is very misleading!! You know that the *vav* usually means "and". Ignorant Jews (Oy, there are too many to count) would think this means that one may eat milk and dairy together!

Comment: @kouty Sorry, typo. I meant to say "meat and dairy together".

Comment: @DanF The Worcestershire sauce is actually a great example of what I'm talking about. Although anchovies are in it, it is labeled pareve and not parve-fish because the OU relies on bitul for this inyan, although not for most other inyonim (ie., inyonim of kashrus). ...  This is to say that OU considers the w' sauce acceptable to be eaten with meat, whereas if it contained the same amount of dairy, they wouldn't

Comment: @SAH I'm not seeing a good analogy, here. Meat and dairy is a kashrut problem; meat and fish is not.  Thus, there may be a stringency *lechatchila* of disallowing dairy in meat; i.e. you can't intentionally put a drop of milk in the huge roast and claim *batul beshishim*. You MAY be allowed to do that with meat and fish combos.

Comment: [related](/q/93197/170)