# Whence "בחזקת בשרי"?

Tags: words, hebrew, meat-and-milk, etymology, chazaka

Besides the main categories of meat, dairy, and pareve (non-meat, non-dairy) foods, two special subcategories of pareve foods are relevant to *halacha* (e.g. *Yore Dea* 93): pareve food cooked using clean meat utensils, and pareve food cooked using clean dairy utensils.

In America, those foods are colloquially known as "[meat/dairy/*other words*] *kelim*" or "[meat/dairy/*other words*] equipment". (*Kelim* means "receptacles".) In fact, what's probably the largest kashruth supervisory agency in the United States, [the Orthodox Union](//oukosher.org/), has in the past allowed products to have a "DE" certification mark, signifying "dairy equipment". And this all makes a lot of sense: the phrase "dairy equipment", or "meat *kelim*", or the like, refers, as a [metonym](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy), to the food that was prepared on such equipment.

In Israel, on the other hand, those foods are called "*b'chezkas [b'sari/chalavi]*", "with/in a *chazaka* of [meat/dairy]". In its normal uses in *halacha*, "*chazaka*" is probably best translated "status": it refers to the state that something or someone is in or can be presumed to be in absent evidence of a change of state. So these foods are called "with a status of meat" or "with a presumption of dairy" or the like. Why? They're not meat or dairy themselves; nor is there any halachic *chazaka* (that I know of) that says that they are. Where does this "*b'chezkas*" wording come from and why is this state referred to by this terminology?

Comment: [related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89211)

Comment: I think it is based on Modern Hebrew (as opposed to Rabbinic Hebrew) in which "bechezkat" means "belonging to" or "under the power of"

Comment: @AdamSimon, oh, thanks, I was unfamiliar with that word. Perhaps post an answer here?

Comment: I thought bchezkas besari was worse than meat equipment. Like food cooked in a dirty meat oven, or fries deep fried in schnitzel oil

Answer (score 0):

They are referred to as B'echezkat because they are always held and used for the purpose of cooking or storing said products. It also can refer to food that's pareve but was cooked in (generally) clean receptacles, so that although the food isn't strictly speaking meaty or milky, it may not be eaten together.